# Genitive: with or without "the"

Tags: articles, possessives, mathematics

I would like to know which variant is correct:

1. "Decimal expansion of the first generalized Euler's constant"
2. "Decimal expansion of first generalized Euler's constant"
3. "Decimal expansion of the first generalized Euler constant"

The problem is the presence of "the" and the genitive "'s".

Comment: _First_ is an old superlative (that's where the final _st_) comes from, and like all superlatives, it is definite and unique, so a definite article is in order. As to the possessive, that depends. Is there a "generalized Euler's constant"? If not, then the fact that there are possibly several of them and reference to only one would suggest that _the first generalized Euler constant_ is the correct phrasing. But it depends on how mathematicians view it.

Comment: What @john said. But missing articles are a standard feature of newspaper "headlinese" - and by association, technical report titles.

Comment: @John Lawler Thank you! Yes, there may be several generalized Euler's constants, i.e. first generalized Euler's constant, second generalized Euler's constant, etc. I took Euler as an example. The actual problem is to know if I can say "Decimal expansion of the first Malmsten's integral" or, should I say, "Decimal expansion of first Malmsten's integral"... Malmsten was a (great) Swedish mathematician. The problem is that one usually says "Fourier series", but also "Kummer's transformation"...

Comment: @John Lawler But there is no a "generalized Euler's constant"

Comment: So you can then say things like _Riemann's Hypothesis states that the real part of all non-trivial zeros of the generalized Riemann zeta function equals -½_. Riemann gets a genitive for the hypothesis but not for the function.

Comment: I choose: "The decimal expansion of the first generalized Euler constant."

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, I would prefer this wording too. But I believe several variants are acceptable and is in wide use. See [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html] (both text and bibliography). There are "Euler's constant", "the Euler constant", "Euler Constant" and "the Eulerian Constant".

Comment: @Iaroslav Concerning "Malmsten's integral" vs "Malmsten integral", it would make sense to stick to the prevailing spelling in existing published papers on this topic.

Comment: And always avoid "The Malmstein's integral".  (See the title of this question.)

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you for your very detailed explanations, it is much more clear now! Your exampe with Riemann is awesome!

Comment: @Iaroslav: You're welcome. Besides, if credit were given where it was due, just about everything in mathematics would be named for Euler. Like [Euler's Formula](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EulersFormula.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: English is not my native language, although I live in the U.S.*

Personally, I would write it as

> the decimal expansion of the first generalized Euler constant

But I believe this is not the only acceptable way. I see no problems while reading

> the decimal expansion of the first generalized Euler's constant

But dropping "the" before "first" sounds wrong.

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Euler-MascheroniConstant.html for examples.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to say that would be:

"Decimal expansion of Euler's first generalized constant."

Comment: The problem is that we do not say "Euler's first" but "first Euler" or "first Euler's"...

Comment: We start with *Euler's constant,* which Euler defined. Somebody else then generalizes it to get a *generalized Euler's constant.* It's not *Euler's generalized constant.* In mathematics, there's no such thing as a *generalized constant*.

Comment: @ Peter Shor  My lack of knowledge of mathematics has been revealed.  Would it be correct to say, "first generalization of Euler's constant?"

Comment: @plmadding I've never seen this wording in math literature.

Comment: @PeterShor This wording is used sometimes in math papers to refer to indexed Stieltjes constants. "generalized" reflects the fact that the Stieltjes constant with index zero \gamma_0 is just the Euler constant \gamma ...

Comment: @PeterShor ...  See, e.g. Knopfmacher, J. "Generalised Euler Constants." Proc. Edinburgh Math. Soc. 21, 25-32, 1978; Kreminski, R. "Newton-Cotes Integration for Approximating Stieltjes (Generalized Euler) Constants." Math. Comput. 72, 1379-1397, 2003; Matsuoka, Y. "Generalized Euler Constants Associated with the Riemann Zeta Function." In Number Theory and Combinatorics. Japan 1984 (Tokyo, Okayama and Kyoto, 1984). Singapore: World Scientific, pp. 279-295, 1985, etc.